# Does "это не значит, что я стану ..." express a determined refusal like "я не стану ..."?

Tags: значения, отрицание

> Я **не** **стану** тебя слушаться.

As I understand it, when "не" directly qualifies the verb "стать", the phrase expresses a determined refusal to do something: "not going to do / not about to do".

> {vs}: Мы с тобой обручились, но это **не** значит, что я **стану** тебя слушаться.

But what about when "не" qualifies the verb "значит" in the main clause, as shown above? Is a strong negation still perceived? Or is it more like a lighter-in-tone, partial negation:

> ..., but that does**n't necessarily** mean that I'm going to ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker, I would say that `не значит` here leaves a certain degree of uncertainty, suggesting an intention not to obey (depending on the actual conditions) rather than strict refusal to obey.

As a comment aside, I find the use of `стать, стану` slightly outdated in your examples. In your first example, it would be slightly more natural to hear a simpler

> Я **не буду** тебя слушаться.

In the second example, the outdated verb `обручиться` also hints that the phrase  refers to the language before the 1917 revolution, rather than to its modern state.

As a non-linguist, I would guess that it is more common nowadays to come across `стать` with the meaning `to become` rather than the refusal you are talking about:

> Мне никогда **не стать** таким знаменитым, как Александр Столетов.

Comment: Hi. How does "Я не собираюсь ..." compare to "Я не стану ..."?

Comment: @Alone-zee They differ by the degree of certainty. `Я не собираюсь` can be translated as `I am not going to`, while `я не стану` is rather `I won't`.

Answer (score 2):

**Это не значит,** = It doesn't mean 
**что я стану тебя слушаться.** = that I will start doing whatever you tell me.

**Слушаться** means listen and do as told. It's what parents often demand of their children: **Слушайся папу!** = Listen to your dad! (and do what he tells you)